# clear a textbox values when i select a last index value from dropdown in asp.net c# but i didnt get this

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on my collage project i have a bill generate form in asp.net c# , my problem is that when i select a last value from database and enter a new data for bill . and then when i save that record that will be store in database and genrate a new index value for dropdown box . so when i select a last value from dropdown i get all clear field in all text boxes. 
but right now when i select a last value fromj dropdown  then i get a record from last inserted values in textbox .
so please can anyone help me..
thank you in advance.
have a nice day.![enter image description here][1]
here is a screen short of my bill genration.
and i select a trans. no from dropdown.

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            string qry1 = "select trans_id from purchase";
            if (qry1 == ddltansid.SelectedValue)
            {
                string qry2 = "update purchase set bill_no=" + txtbillno.Text + ",date = '" + txtdate.Text + "',comp_name='" + ddlcompname.SelectedValue + "',add1='" + txtadd.Text + "',phno=" + txtbxphno.Text + ",cst=" + txtbxcst.Text + ",add_tax=" + txtbxaddtax.Text + ",discount=" + txtbxdisc.Text + ",sub_total=" + txtbxsubtotal.Text + ",g_total=" + txtbxgtotal.Text + ",net_amt=" + txtbxamt.Text + "";
                c.Execute(qry2);
                MessageBox.Show("update successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                str = "Insert into purchase(bill_no,date,comp_name,add1,phno,cst,add_tax,discount,sub_total,g_total,net_amt) values(" + txtbillno.Text + ",'" + txtdate.Text + "','" + ddlcompname.SelectedItem + "','" + txtadd.Text + "'," + txtbxphno.Text + "," + txtbxcst.Text + ",'" + txtbxaddtax.Text + "'," + txtbxdisc.Text + "," + txtbxsubtotal.Text + "," + txtbxgtotal.Text + "," + txtbxnetamt.Text + "";
                c.Execute(str);
                MessageBox.Show("insert successfully";
            }
            str1 = "select medicin_name from pur_tans where name='" + ddlmedicine.SelectedValue + "'";
            str2 = "select item_name from stock_master";
            a = (String.Compare(str1, str2));
            if (a > 0)
            {
                string str3 = "update stock_master set item_qty = (item_qty + '" + txtbxqty.Text + "') where item_name='" + ddlmedicine.SelectedValue + "'";
                c.Execute(str3);
                MessageBox.Show("update successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                string str4 = "insert into stock_master (item_name,item_qty) values('" + ddlmedicine.SelectedValue + "'," + txtbxqty.Text + "";
                c.Execute(str4);
                MessageBox.Show("insert successfully";
            }

        if (ddltansid.SelectedValue == "Add New "
        {

            ddltansid.SelectedIndex = ddltansid.SelectedIndex - 1;
            ddltansid.SelectedValue = ddltansid.SelectedValue + 1;
            string last = ddltansid.SelectedValue;
            if (IsPostBack == true)
            {
                ddltansid.SelectedValue = last.ToString();
                str = "Insert into purchase(bill_no,date,comp_name,add1,phno,cst,add_tax,discount,sub_total,g_total,net_amt) values('' ,'','  ','','','','','','','','')";
                c.Execute(str);
            }


        }
}
```

above is code for insert a value in database

Comment: Your code is asking for an SQL Injection!

Answer (score -1):

Where `ddltansid.SelectedValue == "Add New "` is executed, i would also set the Text property of your textbox to String.Empty.

A little side node: As far as i understand your code, you put userinput directly into your sql query. You should aviod this since it makes your application wounerable to sql insertion attacks.

e.g. if i write in your textbox:

```
 ; drop database --;
```

i can delet your database.

Have a look at **perpared statements in SQL**. You might also be able to score some extra points ;)

Comment: As you suggest clear function. I try many time clear function in my code. but it's still get data from previous row. please give me more suggestion... hello @Chrisi , can you please explain me how  i write in my textbox for clear data. thank you in advace

Comment: for example: `txtbillno.Text = string.Empty;`
do this for every textbox where you dont want to have any text in